# SaveAs Nonstop Loop

Tags: excel, vba

To get to the point of completion for my macro, I start with a downloaded file from the internet which downloads as .xls. After downloading it, I then need to save the file as a .xlsx and change the name of the document to be "dockactivity".

This is a macro that multiple people on multiple devices would be using so I need to keep `Environ$("username")` parts. *(Unless that written wrong of course..)*

This is a macro I use everyday for my job so I wanted to try and have it delete the original downloaded as well.

The problem I am running into: 
It seems to get stuck in an endless loop of saving the file, closing it, opening it, etc.

Here is what I have in now (everything that is before the more cosmetic changes are done to the file). Please note that I am quite a novice at this type of stuff and have pieced together this code from multiple sources online/this site.

```
Sub dockactivity()
'
' dockactivity Macro
'
' push button to run
'
Dim Filename, Pathname, SaveFileName As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim UserName As String

UserName = Environ("username")
Pathname = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("username") & "\Downloads\"
Filename = Dir(Pathname & "Dock_Activity_*.xls")
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Do While Filename <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & Filename)
    wb.CheckCompatibility = True

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.SaveAs Filename:="dockactivity", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Filename = Dir(Pathname & "Dock_Activity_*.xls")
Loop
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

If Dir(Pathname & "Dock_Activity_*.xls") <> "" Then
    Kill (Pathname & "Dock_Activity_*.xls")
End If

Workbooks.Open (Pathname & "dockactivity.xlsx")

Windows("dockactivity.xlsx").Activate
```

Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: hi. i believe that u have to call dir function without parameters inside the loop, like this Filename = Dir. if u call with parameters it returns always the first file.

Comment: Luis is right! use `Filename = Dir` within the loop.